# Nodejs installation not working in solaris

Tags: node.js, installation, solaris, sunos

I have a 64 bit SunOS (Solaris) where i have installed (extracted) nodejs in that machine.

when i execute the "node" command it throws an error "-bash: /export/home/toml/das/node-v0.12.7-sunos-x64/bin/node: Invalid argument"

I don't know how to resolve this issue. Note: i have download the tar file from this location - https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.5/node-v0.12.5-sunos-x64.tar.gz

Note : we have a SPARC BOX

Comment: What do you get if you run `node -v`? Same error?

Comment: Note we have a SPARC machine

Comment: node -v command gives the following result -bash: ./node: Invalid argument

Comment: Can you check if the node path is exported properly?

Comment: Post the output from `file /export/home/toml/das/node-v0.12.7-sunos-x64/bin/node` and `ldd /export/home/toml/das/node-v0.12.7-sunos-x64/bin/node`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a SPARC binary - you can't use an x64 (64-bit x86) binary on a SPARC machine.
"Invalid argument" is the poor error message shown when you try to run the wrong type of binary on Solaris.

Comment: Sir! Nodejs is a popular and upcoming framework. Nodejs doesn't come with SPARC libraries. Can Oracle compile and distribute those binaries for their client. Is this possible ?

Comment: Since node.js is open source, Oracle could decide to put in the effort to port it to SPARC processors and release that, but so far it has not done so.   But there is nothing restricting this to Oracle either - anyone else with a strong interest in doing this can do so as well.   Until you either do that or can convince someone to do that though, you're left with the choice of using a different language/framework on SPARC, or using node.js on a different platform that is already supported.